# Hyperlink is not clickable in Ext. JS html editor

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Hyperlink is not clickable in Ext. JS html editor in below piece of code.

I have checked [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878785/how-to-make-hyper-links-clickable-in-extjs-htmleditor/20899340) , which couldn't help for me.

**Script**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-classic/resources/theme-classic-all.css"
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function (){
        Ext.create('Ext.form.HtmlEditor',{
            width: 650,
            height: 150,
            renderTo: document.getElementById('htmlEditorId')
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="htmlEditorId" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Here in DummyURL, I have given a valid value but still not clickable also not even working with Ctrl+click.

I am new to Ext. JS could someone help me out here.

What modification i could do in existing script to make it work properly.?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK links are not clickable not only in WYSIWYG editors but also in most of text processing applications. Anyway you can create a preview panel with clickable html, something like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            viewModel: {
                htmlString: ''
            },
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            defaults: {
                height: 200
            },
            bodyPadding: 5,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: "Editor",
                flex: 1,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'htmleditor',
                    bind: {
                        value: '{htmlString}'
                    }

                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: "Preview",
                bind: {
                    html: '{htmlString}'
                },
                margin: '5 0 0 0'
            }],

            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```